# Classifying list of filenames into its respective types

Tags: python, string, list

So I have this list that contains lots of filenames in a directory with its respective types. Say that the list look like this:

```
list = ['apple-20220103.csv', 'apple_tea-20220304.csv', '20220203-apple_town.csv', 'apple_town20220101.csv']
```

and the types of file are stored in a `.csv` file like this:

```
,type
0,apple
1,apple_tea
2,apple_town
```

I want to classify each filename in the list into its respective type of file and put them into a dictionary. Say that the dictionary would look like this after processed:

```
dictionary = {
     'apple':['apple-20220103.csv'],
     'apple_tea':['apple_tea-20220304.csv'],
     'apple_town':['20220203-apple_town.csv', 'apple_town20220101.csv'
}
```

The question is how can I ensure so that `apple` would not receive any file besides `apple-20220103.csv`, despite other filenames also contain the word `apple` in it? I've tried using simple regex matching, and the result still has `apple_tea` and `apple_town` filenames in `apple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match everything which is **not** a number or a dash by the pattern given below.
Then you can use the complete match as a key for your dictionary.

```
your_list = ['apple-20220103.csv', 'apple_tea-20220304.csv', '20220203-apple_town.csv', 'apple_town20220101.csv']

pattern = '[^0-9\-]+'

for element in your_list:
    a=re.search(pattern, element[:-4])
    print(a.group())

# Output
apple
apple_tea
apple_town
apple_town
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this is the most suitable answer for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at word boundary `\b`

```
import re
filenames = ['apple-20220103.csv', 'apple_tea-20220304.csv', '20220203-apple_town.csv', 'apple_town20220101.csv']
categories = ['apple','apple_tea','apple_town']
for category in categories:
    print(category)
    pattern = r'\b' + re.escape(category) + r'\b'
    for filename in filenames:
        if re.search(pattern, filename):
            print(filename)
    print()
```

gives output

```
apple
apple-20220103.csv

apple_tea
apple_tea-20220304.csv

apple_town
20220203-apple_town.csv
```

From [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

> `\b`
>
> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a
> word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that
> formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W`
> character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of
> the string.(...)

I also use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to make sure that if character of special meaning will appear in category name (e.g. dot) they will be treated as literal character.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to the problem could be to use the library `difflib`.

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib
list = ['apple-20220103.csv', 'apple_tea-20220304.csv', '20220203-apple_town.csv', 'apple_town20220101.csv']
csv_file = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

thisdict = {}

for row in csv_file.iterrows():
    close = difflib.get_close_matches(row[1][1], list, len(list), 0)
    thisdict[str(row[1][1])] = close[0]
print(thisdict)
```

This produces the following output.

```
{'apple': 'apple-20220103.csv', 'apple_tea': 'apple_tea-20220304.csv', 'apple_town': 'apple_town20220101.csv'}
```

Notice that only the closest string gets put into the dictionary.